# How electric charges behave in different motion conditions?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, magnetic-fields

Electric charge at constant velocity produces magnetic an electric field but the particle does not radiate. But, in accelerated motion the particle radiates. But light is also a radiation and the particles move at a constant velocity ($c$).

Could you help me out with this dilemma and correct me if I'm wrong somewhere?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your last line doesn't make any sense, what does light traveling at c have to do with this?

Comment: Light is a radiation but the particles aren't accelerated, just at constant speed!

Comment: There is a difference between particles radiating and radiation itself.

Answer (score -1):

Light does not radiate. Light is a stream of photons.

These photons are emitted by subatomic particles - the particles emit photons - and exist until they are absorbed by another subatomic particles.

Emission occurs

- when the kinetic energy of the particles decreases
- or when the electron returns from an excited state in atoms.